I expected a menu collection but got objects, why?
I have a cashier page that goes to the layout page, I use the blade template in Laravel 11, namely {{ $slot }}, continuing with the problem, I experienced an error, namely Expecting a collection for the menu but getting an object. why is that??? and also when I click on the category that I am looping I make it a navbars Error: Expected a collection for items but got object, in a moment I will show the code and appearance of my website [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/vTAsqP0o.png), I'll explain in a moment if I click on all menus the error message that comes out is Error: Expected a collection for menus but got object. If I click on a category, for example food, an error will appear. Error: Expected a collection for items but got object.

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Employe;

use App\Models\Menus;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function kasir(Request $request, $id = null)
    {
        $title = 'Kasir';
        $menus = collect();
        $items = collect();

        if ($id === null) {
            if ($request->is('all-menus')) {
                $menus = Menus::all();
                $title = 'All Menu';
            } else {
                $items = Category::all();
            }
        } else {
            $category = Category::find($id);
            if (!$category) {
                abort(404, 'Category not found');
            }
            $title = $category->name;
            $category->load('menus'); // <--- Eager load the menus relationship
            $menus = $category->menus;
        }


        \Log::info('Menus:', $menus->toArray());
        \Log::info('Items:', $items->toArray());

        return view('employee.kasir', compact('menus', 'title', 'items'));
    }
}

<x-employee.layout>
    <x-slot:title>{{ $title }}</x-slot:title>
    <div class="w-full lg:flex lg:justify-evenly lg:w-3/2 mx-auto">
        <div class="px-4 w-full lg:w-2/3">
            <h2 class="text-4xl font-bold mb-4 dark:text-primary">Kasir</h2>

            <div class="scroll-container mb-5">
                <ul class="category-list flex items-center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('all.menus') }}"
                            class="{{ request()->fullUrl() === url('/page/employee/categories') ? 'text-orange border-b-2 border-yellow dark:text-primary dark:border-primary' : 'hover:text-yellow text-gray-600 dark:text-blue-100' }} pb-2">
                            All Menu
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    @if ($items instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)
            @foreach ($items as $object)
                @if (is_object($object))
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('category.show', $object->id) }}"
                            class="{{ request()->is('/page/employee/categories/' . $object->id) ? 'text-orange border-b-2 border-yellow dark:text-primary dark:border-primary' : 'hover:text-yellow text-gray-600 dark:text-blue-100' }} pb-2">
                            {{ $object->name }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li>
                        <p>Error: Unexpected value of type {{ gettype($object) }} found in items collection.</p>
                    </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>Error: Expected a collection for items but got {{ gettype($items) }}.</p>
        @endif

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="grid mx-auto pb-[420px] lg:pb-2 grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 gap-2">
                @if ($menus instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)
                @foreach ($menus as $menu)
                    <div class="bg-white dark:bg-dark p-3 w-full transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out mx-auto relative hover:scale-105 hover:border-orange hover:border dark:hover:border-primary rounded-xl cursor-pointer lg:w-60">
                        <div class="absolute right-2 top-2 group">
                            <button class="hover:bg-slate-100 dark:hover:bg-slate-500 w-8 h-8 rounded-lg relative">
                                <i class="bi bi-info-circle dark:text-primary"></i>
                                <div class="hidden group-hover:block absolute top-10 -right-5 min-w-56 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg p-4 z-50">
                                    <h4 class="font-semibold dark:text-primary">{{ $menu->name }}</h4>
                                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm">Kategori: {{ $menu->category->name }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm">Harga: Rp. {{ number_format($menu->price, 0, ',', '.') }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm">Bahan-bahan: {{ $menu->description }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $menu->image) }}" class="w-2/3 lg:w-2/3 mx-auto" alt="{{ $menu->name }}">
                        <h4 class="mt-4 font-semibold text-sm lg:text-lg dark:text-primary">{{ $menu->name }}</h4>
                        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                            <p class="text-gray-600 text-xs lg:text-sm">{{ $menu->category->name }}</p>
                            <p class="text-orange font-semibold text-xs lg:text-sm dark:text-primary">Rp. {{ number_format($menu->price, 0, ',', '.') }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <p>Error: Expected a collection for menus but got {{ gettype($menus) }}.</p>
            @endif
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr class="my-4 hidden sm:block">
        <div
            class="w-full fixed bottom-0 left-0 z-50 dark:bg-dark lg:border-none lg:rounded-xl dark:border dark:border-primary bg-white p-5 shadow-xl rounded-t-xl lg:relative lg:w-1/2 lg:bottom-auto lg:left-auto lg:shadow-none lg:bg-transparent lg:p-0 lg:z-0">
            <div
                class="lg:bg-white dark:bg-dark lg:dark:border lg:dark:border-primary lg:p-5 lg:w-full lg:rounded-xl overflow-x-auto">
                <h4 class="text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl font-semibold mb-6 md:mb-5 dark:text-primary">Order #003</h4>
                <div id="scroll-menu" class="p-5 w-full overflow-y-auto lg:max-h-52 ">
                    <div class="flex items-center mb-3">
                        <img src="{{ asset('dist/assets admin/dish_01.png') }}" alt="Cheesey Chicken"
                            class="w-12 h-12 md:w-16 md:h-16 rounded">
                        <div class="ml-4 flex-1">
                            <p class="font-semibold text-gray-800 text-xs md:text-base lg:text-lg dark:text-white">
                                Cheesey Chicken
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-gray-600 text-xs md:text-sm lg:text-base dark:text-white">Rp. 35,000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 md:space-x-4">
                            <button
                                class="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-slate-300 w-8 h-8 md:w-10 md:h-10 rounded-full">
                                <i class="bi bi-dash w-full dark:text-black"></i>
                            </button>
                            <p class="text-gray-800 text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg dark:text-primary">1</p>
                            <button
                                class="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-slate-300 w-8 h-8 md:w-10 md:h-10 rounded-full">
                                <i class="bi bi-plus dark:text-black"></i>
                            </button>
                            <p class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg dark:text-white">Rp.
                                35,000</p>
                            <button
                                class="bg-rose-100 dark:bg-rose-500 text-red-600 w-8 h-8 md:w-10 md:h-10 rounded-xl">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash dark:text-white"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div class="flex justify-between mb-2">
                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm md:text-base dark:text-primary">Subtotal</p>
                    <p class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-sm md:text-base dark:text-primary">Rp. 229,000</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm md:text-base dark:text-primary">Pajak</p>
                    <p class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-sm md:text-base dark:text-primary">Rp. 12,000</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4 border-dashed">
                <div class="flex justify-between mb-5">
                    <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm md:text-base dark:text-primary">Total</p>
                    <p class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-lg md:text-xl dark:text-primary">Rp. 241,000</p>
                </div>
                <button id="checkout-button" data-modal-target="authentication-modal"
                    data-modal-toggle="authentication-modal"
                    class="bg-green-600 dark:bg-slate-700 dark:hover:bg-slate-500 hover:bg-green-400 text-white py-2 md:py-3 w-full rounded-lg">
                    Checkout
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="authentication-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
        class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 justify-center items-center w-full md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
        <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
            <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4 md:p-5 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                    <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                        Payment
                    </h3>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="end-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ms-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                        data-modal-hide="authentication-modal">
                        <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6" />
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="p-4 md:p-5">
                    <form class="space-y-4" action="#">
                        <div class="relative w-full">
                            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                    fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill text-slate-400" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="voice-search"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="relative w-full">
                            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                    fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cash-stack text-slate-400" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M1 3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1zm7 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4" />
                                    <path
                                        d="M0 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm3 0a2 2 0 0 1-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" id="voice-search"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <button
                            class="w-full bg-red p-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-rose-300 text-medium font-semibold text-white dark:bg-primary">Confirm</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-employee.layout>


I've asked friends and AI but it's been more than 1 month now and I'm still experiencing this and confused about how to solve it, I hope you all can help me

The gettype function cannot differentiate between Eloquent collection object and other types of object, so it won't help in this case. Instead of gettype($menus) you should try dd($menus) from Laravel. It will give much more information for debugging purposes. Once you do that, you can edit this question and provide it with new info

collect() generates an instance of the type Illuminate\Support\Collection
Menu::all() returns an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection which if a subclass of the former.
To make sure that everything works you should adjust your blade check to the following
@if ($menus instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection)
    
@endif


I've done it but the food doesn't appear when I click all menu, and I also experience the same error when I click category "
Error: Expected a collection for items but got object."
